# Customize WooCommerce single product sharing icons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce single product page, there is sharing icons by default (Facebook, Twitter, GooglePlus, and Telegram). I want to change this icons and use other social medias, for example WhatsApp,... I searched every code pages of the theme and WooCommerce plugin but I couldn't find where it reads this. so I wanted to know where can I find and change this code or if there is a filter code that I can change the social icons with it.
Edit: there is a switch to show sharing icons at product's details page.
this code is showing the switch at admin panel:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">sharing product</th>
    <td>
        <label class="ios-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="product-sharing" value="1" <?php checked( irk_get_option( 'product_sharing' ), 1 ); ?>>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

but I couldn't find the code for retrieving 'irk_get_option' and showing the icons. there was the below code at single-page.php of the theme, but it isn't for product detail page and doesn't change the icons there.

```
 <footer class="card-footer">
                            <?php
                            if ( irk_get_option( 'short_link' ) ) {
                                echo '<div class="short-link float-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="click for copy."><i class="mdi mdi-link-variant"></i>' . wp_get_shortlink() . '</div>';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="sharing list-inline">
                                <a href="https://telegram.me/share/url?url=<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>&text=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" class="list-inline-item">
                                    <i class="mdi mdi-telegram"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="list-inline-item">
                                    <i class="mdi mdi-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>&url=<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="list-inline-item">
                                    <i class="mdi mdi-whatsapp"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="list-inline-item">
                                    <i class="mdi mdi-google-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
```

Comment: Have you checked out the templates of WooCommerce? You can overwrite them to add another social icon. Since I never saw social icons in WooCommerce, you need to check this out by yourself. I think this comes from your theme you use.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far!.

Comment: @Bhautik I edited the post. I don't know how should I do this with code. and couldn't find the original code to edit it.

Comment: I found the file, with the help of multi-find software. and could change the code successfully.